# Pyspark, initializing spark programmatically : IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource

Tags: python, pyspark

When creating a spark context in Python, I get the following error.

```
 app_name="my_app"
 master="local[*]"
 sc = SparkContext(appName=app_name, master=master)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)

....

pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

The spark launcher seems to be failing somehow.

Answer (score 5):

This was happening due to preexisting env variables, that conflicted. I deleted them in the python program and it works smoothly now.

ex:

```
import  os
#check if pyspark env vars are set and then reset to required or delete.   
del os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']
```

*The correct solution is to delete it in .bashrc or .zshrc or whatever the env initialization scripts that would be initializing it. But could not find it in .bash_profile(mac) (.bashrc or /etc/environment.conf). Will update answer if the location is found*

Comment: wow that worked!  How did you figure it out? Is there a reference/url with more info?

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find any reference, it took some time to figure out that env variables exported in ~/.bash_profile were conflicting to the python script.

Comment: This worked for me to. But that is strange because I removed this variable from .bashrc and sourced it to no effect. I had to delete the variable in Python script to make it work.